# SQL Server Replication Licensing

Tags: sql-server, replication, merge-replication, sql-server-express, license

Production database is hosted on a SQL Server Standard instance and is replicated using merge replication with web synchronization to 10 subscriber databases hosted on 10 separate SQL Express server instances. Each subscriber database is accessible by another 5 local users, who can read/write/process the data. SQL Server Standard instance is licensed through CAL scheme.

1. Do we need to have CAL for every of the 5 local users on each subscriber server instance?
2. Do we need to have CAL for every SQL Server Express instance? Web synchronization is achieved through IIS Server on the same server with the SQL Server Standard instance.
3. Do we need to license every SQL Express instance, or it is free for use?
4. There is an additional capability for 20 users, to access the production database directly through a desktop thin client application, where they can read/write/process data, which data are then replicated to every SQL Server Express instance. Do we need CAL for every user of this thin client application? The application is communicating with SQL Server through ODBC using one specific login user credentials.

Thanx

Comment: Licensing questions are off-topic here. Please talk to your sales rep.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Express edition is free of charge, and you don't have to license it. CALs (Client Access Licenses) are only applicable to paid versions of SQL Server (Enterprise, Standard). If you are adding users to SQL Server Express for merge replication as subscribers, that is free of charge.

Here's the link for [SQL Server 2019 licensing](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/licensing/product-licensing/sql-server) and for information on the features and components of SQL Server, you can refer to the following [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2019?view=sql-server-ver16). This link may come in handy if you decide to update/upgrade in the future.

Comment: "If you are adding users to SQL Server Express for merge replication as subscribers, that is free of charge": this is very helpful, but without intention to question your opinion, is there any reference?

Comment: this is not based on my opinion. The link i shared above is a good reference and it includes a comparison of SQL Server Editions. from the link says _"SQL Server Express edition is the entry-level, free database and is ideal for learning and building desktop and small server data-driven applications. It is the best choice for independent software vendors, developers, and hobbyists building client applications."_ meaning you can do whatever you want and it is free when you use SQL Server Express.